# Regression analysis vs outlier detection

Tags: regression, outliers

I have seen many examples where even if the goal is to find outliers, the first step is to go through linear (or any other) regression and then move on to outlier identification. Why?

If one wishes to find outliers only, can't regression analysis be skipped by using methods like [68–95–99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)?

Comment: Outlier detection is often one of those hand-wavy areas of statistics relying on subjective or context-dependent definitions. One thing to be wary of is the implicit assumption of normality you get when you use that 68-95-99 rule. Furthermore, it may be useful to apply some regression to see if the variability in the outputs is due to drastic differences in the inputs. For instance, fit a linear trend to x = (1.5, 2, 3, 3.1, 50), and y=(6, 8.2, 11.5, 13, 210). Is the last observation an outlier? Using your rule it would be, but a simple linear regression would show it as a reasonable value

Comment: @DavidKozak: Thanks. When you say, "**Using your rule it would be**", does that raises the question of being careful while selecting methodology for outlier identification?

Comment: From a purely typographic perspective, note that the preferred style of titles in the SE system is *sentence case* (cf, [Title Case or Sentence Case?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252624/1217536)).  There might be exceptions in some of the smaller sites, but this is certainly true of [SO] & [stats.SE]. Also, we prefer you don't add "thanks", or some variant thereof, to your questions (even though my Mother would certainly approve ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for outliers in a single time series by using 1-, 2-, or 3-standard deviations as thresholds of outlierness is often of limited interest.  Usually, this type of investigation is associated with an explicit dependent variable Y and several independent X variables.  In other words, your objective is to estimate and explain the behavior of Y by a bunch of associated or causal variables Xs.

Given the above, what does investigating outliers entail?  Well, there are two types of outliers.  The first type consists of estimates associated with large errors or residuals.  This type of outliers is measured as studentized residuals.  Your second type consists of X outliers, where their values at a given point deviates significantly from their average.  This type of outlier is called Hat-Leverage.

So, what do you do with these studentized residuals and Hat-Leverage measures?  They are actually combined into a third and last measure of outlierness: Cook's D value.  The higher this value the more a specific datapoint will have an influence on the regression coefficients of your regression model.  To fully understand those concepts learn how to interpret and graph an Influence Plot in R.

An Influence Plot in R will readily identify for you the data points that have the most influence on your regression coefficients.  So, next you rerun your regression by removing one of those influential data point at a time (with the highest Cook's D value), and observe how much your regression coefficients have moved.  If a couple of data points pull in the same direction you may consider removing them both from your regression and observe how much your regression coefficients have moved.

If you are interested in testing your regression for outliers further, there is an entire family of Robust Regressions catered to do exactly that (Ridge Regression, Quantile Regression, M-M Regression).  So, you could rerun your model using one or more of those Robust Regression models.

Ideally, when you rerun your regressions removing the most influential outliers or when you use a Robust Regression, in all cases your regression coefficients would remain relatively stable vs. your original regression.  Similarly, the statistical significance of all your independent variables Xs should also remain reasonably stable.  If they are not stable, you may have explicit justifications or explanations for the mentioned instability.  And, that is fine.  If you do not have an acceptable explanation it suggests that you consider removing the variables associated with unstable coefficients and weakening statistical significance.

Outlier testing is one of the most important aspect of testing a model.

Notice that in this entire discourse, I did not speak of any outliers of Y.  By themselves, they are not always interesting.  On the other hand, the difference between Y and Y estimate (the residual) is extremely interesting.  But, as indicated residual outliers are only part of outlier investigation and testing.

Comment: Thank you @Sympa, for detailed answer. It's helpful to know about regression and outlier identification flow using different techniques. Based on your answer, to me it seems that outlier detection and regression go hand in hand. I was trying to understand, whether outlier detection can be purely done without going into regression analysis. However, it seems that isn't the case and not a good approach either.

Comment: Overall I think you are right.  And, you pretty much got my message.  An outlier of Y on its own may not be that informative.  Often, you have an outlier of Y that is actually very well fitted by the regression model estimate.  In such a case, an outlier of Y is well explained by the model and is no big deal.  You want to focus your statistical analysis on the other types of outliers as explained in my answer.